# How initWithObjectAndkeys using variable in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode6, nsdictionary

How initWithObjectAndkeys using variable, I want loop through for no of items in category, please help

if I use NSArray like this

```
data = [saved_result valueForKey:@"data"];
        NSLog(@"%@",[data valueForKey:@"category"]);

         NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:data, nil];
    for (id tempObject in myArray) {
        NSLog(@"Single element: %@", tempObject);

        }
```

here is the content of the NSArray type variable  save data, It will help you to understand the code.
Saved Result =

```
(
            {
            data =         {
                amount = 10;
                category = Food;
                dealid = 28;
                enddate = "2016-12-31";
                retailername = mukesh;
                startingdate = "2015-01-10";
                title = gter;
            };
            msg = "deals found";
            status = true;
        },
            {
            data =         {
                amount = 10;
                category = Shopping;
                dealid = 44;
                enddate = "2016-12-31";
                retailername = divya;
                startingdate = "2015-01-10";
                title = welcome;
            };
            msg = "deals found";
            status = true;
        }
            )


2015-02-24 17:09:57.985 Raott[3316:59975] Single element: (
        {
        amount = 10;
        category = Food;
        dealid = 28;
        enddate = "2016-12-31";
        retailername = mukesh;
        startingdate = "2015-01-10";
        title = gter;
    },
        {
        amount = 10;
        category = Shopping;
        dealid = 44;
        enddate = "2016-12-31";
        retailername = divya;
        startingdate = "2015-01-10";
        title = welcome;
    },
        {
        amount = 859;
        category = Shopping;
        dealid = 53;
        enddate = "2016-12-31";
        retailername = mukesh;
        startingdate = "2015-01-10";
        title = ghk;
    },
        {
        amount = 50;
        category = Shopping;
        dealid = 64;
        enddate = "2016-12-31";
        retailername = mukesh;
        startingdate = "2015-01-10";
        title = "new deal";
    },
        {
        amount = 12;
        category = Shopping;
        dealid = 68;
        enddate = "2016-12-31";
        retailername = mukesh;
        startingdate = "2015-01-10";
        title = hello;
    },
        {
        amount = 213;
        category = Food;
        dealid = 69;
        enddate = "2016-12-31";
        retailername = mukesh;
        startingdate = "2015-01-10";
        title = fgfdg;
    }
)
```

Comment: Converting array into dictionary   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414852/convert-nsarray-to-nsdictionary

Comment: initWithObjectsAndKeys: requires 2 arrays. One for the object and other for the key. You are passing only a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your saved result is `NSArray` ie `arrResult` , so we will `loop` through it.

```
for(NSDictionary *dictObject in arrResult)
{
   //Get Data Dictionary
   NSDictionary *dictData = [dictObject valueForKey:@"data"];
  //Now have data so traverse
  for (NSString*strkey in dictData) {
        id value = [dictData objectForKey:strkey];
        NSLog(@"id = %@",value);
    }
}
```