# NSAarry to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, unrecognized-selector

I have an NSArray that looks like this

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"main: %@", [dataDict valueForKey:@"main"]);
main: [{"city": "dallas", "description": "this is my test description"}]
```

And I am trying to turn it into a NSDictionary so I get get element like `[mainDict objectForKey@"city"]`

So I tried this

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[mainArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"city"]);
```

Thinking it would get the first element in `mainArray` and then the object that I want but I keep getting this error

```
[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

How can I make the NSAarry into a NSDictionary?

Thanks

Comment: @DevangGoswami I got the same error

Comment: mainArray is string not a array so please first convert it into array and then do your code. It will work perfect

Comment: nsdictionary *abc=@{@"city": @"dallas", @"description": @"this is my test description"}

Comment: @DevangGoswami I am not defining `mainArray` like that, that is what I see when I NSLog it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert NSArray to NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414852/convert-nsarray-to-nsdictionary)

Comment: @Jens my question is different than the one you linked to as I am getting my array from a dictionary to start with

Comment: The Content of your question is completely changed. And after the Change it is very unclear. You get a NSDictionary and want to change it into a NSDictionary ??

Comment: lol just make a for loop to fetch data from it .. for (NSDictionary *d in mainArray){
nslog (@"%@",[d objectForKey :@"key"]);
}

Comment: @Jens I just added a few lines to show I was not declaring the mainArray, I am getting it from another NSDictionary, which was my mistake in not explaining correctly first, but not I think this should be reopened

Comment: @DevangGoswami now I get this error `[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: print d put a break point there if that dont work then change loop  :   for (NSDictionary *d in [[dataDict valueForKey:@"main"] objectAtIndex:0])

Comment: @spenf10 Please have a look on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a for loop for list when you get response in [{},{}] format that means its a list of elements . Or you can ask your API developer to correct the error .

Any ways simple solution here is :

```
for (NSDictionary *d in [dataDict valueForKey:@"main"]){ 
NSlog (@"%@",d); 
NSlog (@"%@",[d objectForKey :@"city"]); 
}
```

Comment: That gives this error `[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance `

Comment: for (NSDictionary *d in [[dataDict valueForKey:@"main"] objectAtIndex:0])

Comment: when I did that it fails on the line of the for loop with this `-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Log d and paste the value here , Please

Comment: it never gets there with for loop of this `for (NSDictionary *d in [dataDict valueForKey:@"main"])` it also fails on that line

Comment: When I log `NSLog(@"main: %@", [dataDict valueForKey:@"main"]);` I see `main: [{"city": "dallas", "description": "this is my test description"}]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97258/discussion-between-devang-goswami-and-spenf10).

Comment: Join the chat bro @spenf10 Try out this code ... .pastebin.com/haHm1K60

Answer (score 0):

Your error is saying mainarray is not a NSArray, it is NSString. So please check like this

```
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"main: %@", [dataDict valueForKey:@"main"]);


    if ([[dataDict valueForKey:@"main"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

        NSArray *mainArray = [dataDict valueForKey:@"main"];

        NSLog(@"City == %@",[[mainArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"city"]);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"mainarray is kind of -> %@", NSClassFromString([dataDict valueForKey:@"main"]));
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
NSArray *mainArray = @[@{@"city":@"dallas", @"description":@"this is my test description"}];
 NSLog(@"%@", [[mainArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"city"]);
```

no problem ....

Comment: see my addition, that is what I see when I log that main data, I am not defining it that way